# CORS Error: Setting cookies in AWS Lambda via API Gateway for custom domain with authorization

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to write an AWS Lambda function that sets a Cloudfront Signed Cookie to access a private Cloudfront (S3) endpoint (using [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@apalshah/node-js-serve-private-content-using-aws-cloudfront-992e846259ae) as a guide).

Because my app uses AWS Cognito for authorization, instead of writing a custom authorization function I figured I would just use a Cognito authorizer in API Gateway and send a JWT Token.

I've been able to successfully set a cookie via the function in my browser, but am having problems setting the correct domain I need to access the cookie info. The cookie is setting the domain for the address of the API Gateway: `xxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

Because of this, I figured I would just use a custom domain name on the API Gateway endpoint (which routes the call through a Cloudfront endpoint). The problem I'm having is that the Cognito Authorization header for API Gateway necessitates an `OPTIONS` call, which gives me the error:

```
Access to fetch at 'xxxxx' from origin 'xxxxx' has been blocked 
by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access 
control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

Any tips on the best way to fix this? Any way to set the correct domain without using a custom domain for the API? Alternatively, should I just send the cookie info as JSON and set it in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a problem with the Cloudfront Edge distribution on the API Gateway domain name endpoint. AWS was redirecting the caller to the nearest endpoint which was causing problems with the OPTIONS call. By switching the custom domain directly to one specific regional endpoint, I was able to solve the problem.